# NYSIIS algorithm in Perl

Tags: perl, character

I am trying to use the NYSIIS module in perl: http://search.cpan.org/~krburton/String-Nysiis-1.00/Nysiis.pm

I tried the sample program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.10.0;
use String::Nysiis qw(nysiis);

my $enc = nysiis($string);

print nysiis('Larry'),"\n"; # should print LARY
```

It does print LARY, but it also gives me an error of: "Use of uninitialized value $string in uc at C:/Perl/site/lib/String/Nysiis.pm line 24."

When I did ppm install String::Nysiis, I am told that "No missing packages to install."

How may I prevent this warning (or error) from being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling it with an uninitialized variable in this line:

```
my $enc = nysiis($string);
```

Take that line out, or initialize $string first (and then use $enc).

Comment: @user2096518, You missed it because you didn't use `use strict; use warnings;`. Always do.